# How can I see what zone or site of origin caspol considers a piece of code to belong to?

Tags: .net, windows, permissions, caspol

I am trying to get used to caspol because the downloaded projects for software books I use invariably won't run because "the project location is not trusted". I understand I need to use caspol to resolve this by creating a membership condition. MSDN caspol documentation recommends not using a URL. How I can't see how I can view the zone or site of origin that caspol considers a piece of code to be associated with. (Yes, I know what site I used, but this has been a consistent issue under x64 Win 7 and I want to know what caspol thinks the answer is, I certainly don't know what zone the code is in).

As a side note, I am not even sure if I was using the URL what the proper URL would be, is it the location of the solution file, the directory containing the source files, what?

Comment: Have you tried `caspol -rsp` or `caspol -rsg` ?

Comment: Visual studio throws up the warning even with a project with only uncompiled source code. caspol -rsp requires an assembly. However compiling the source code and running caspol -rsp showed the resulting executable had unrestricted User permissions, but no machine or enterprise permissions. Running caspol -rsg showed the executable belonged to the All Code group & My Computer zone. So it looks like caspol rsg worked. So you have to compile the code first to use caspol rsg, but then you can find the code group. If you post that as an answer and no one has a more direct approach I can accept it.

Comment: Would still like to know how "site of origin" can be seen.